# Scrapy is provides no output with xpath selector

Tags: xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

This is the code I am trying to run in scrapy shell to get the headline of the article from dailymail.co.uk.

```
headline = response.xpath("//div[@id='js-article-text']/h2/text()").extract()
```

---

```
$ scrapy shell "https://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-8257569/Shia-LaBeouf-revealed-heavily-tattoo-torso-goes-shirtless-run-hot-pink-shorts.html"
```

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverFlow, @ShubhanshuRathi !** What is your question? Please elaborate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up an user-agent with your request and it should work :

```
scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" "https://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-8257569/Shia-LaBeouf-revealed-heavily-tattoo-torso-goes-shirtless-run-hot-pink-shorts.html"
response.xpath("//div[@id='js-article-text']/h2/text()").extract()
```

Output :

```
Shia LaBeouf reveals his heavily tattoo torso as he goes shirtless for a run in hot pink shorts
```

Comment: Thanks :) .Its working.  Can you please explain why we have to do this. ?
What if we want to add this into the file we are running scrapy shell? I m using scraoy shell to just test my path and debugging, What changes should I make in my python file to get this running.

Comment: Some websites don't want you scrape their content. So they add a layer of protection for detecting bots. For your spider, you should check https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider . Use custom settings with `DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS : { 'user-agent': 'useragentofyourchoice'  }` or set up the user agent directly in your settings.py (`USER_AGENT = 'useragentofyourchoice'`).

Comment: So do we have any source from where we can get a list of user-agents and use them randomly so that they can't detect us?

Comment: You should check https://pypi.org/project/Scrapy-UserAgents/ and https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-fake-useragent/. Reference : https://frama.link/r7vjJwcQ

Comment: f you are making requests from a single IP Address, rotating user agents will not help you from getting blocked. It will increase the changes to get blocked instead. Anti-Scraping measures will flag requests as unusual when they see the same IP address sending many requests with different user agents. And we are rotating the IP address the crawler is getting too slow. Is there any other option where we can prevent the bot getting blocked.

Comment: My knowledge is limited in this field of area. Besides rotating proxies and using custom user agents, I don't see any other option. My advice would be to switch alternatively between mobile and desktop user-agent when you're making your requests.

Comment: Thankyou so much. :)